# Reading a file within module

Tags: python-3.x, file, module, package, init

I'm struggling with - I think - a very simple problem.

I'm developing a custom package with a structure like this:

```
mypackage
|      |-> __init__.py
|      |-> module1.py
|      |-> module2.py
|      |-> module3.py
|      |-> externalfile.xml
```

The external file is read by a fuction in module1.
I can easily and obviously do it if I launch module1 in terminal. But when I try to launch that function within another script, I have a FileNotFoundError traceback.

My question is: why in this situation I can't be able to open a file that lives witin the package itself?

```
# module1.py

[...]
def myfunction():
    with open('externalfile.xml', 'r') as fh:
        xml = fh.read()
    return xml
```

```
# __init__.py

import mypackage.module1
[...]
```

```
# myOtherScript.py

from mypackage import module1

[...]
script = module1.myfunction()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File --myOtherScript.py--, line xx, in <module>
    from mypackage import module1
  File "-\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\mypackage\__init__.py", line xx, in <module>
    with open('exeternalfile.xml', 'r') as fh:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'externalfile.xml'
```

Comment: Try using `import os; print(os.getcwd())` to get the current working directory. I bet you it is not what you expect.

Comment: Totally agreee. But I can't understand why a file wihin a module can't be read by a function in the same package. I knwo that I'm working on a local folder, but in my mind, if I import a module, I import everything within the module...

Comment: Because you aren't running the script, your interpreter is. Your interpreter has its own working directory, and by just using the filename it will try to find it in its path. There are tools offered by `os` to work around this, and I suggest looking up how to get the path to the directory of a file.

Comment: Right. I play around with os and path, so I solved the problem. Thank you very much. My aim was to find a integrated solution, but I undestand the problem with interpreter. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# module1.py

import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))  # Returns the absolute path to your package folder

def myfunction():
    with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "externalfile.xml"), 'r') as fh:
        xml = fh.read()
    return xml
```

Comment: Would prefer the use of `os.join(BASE_DIR, 'externalfile.xml')`.

Comment: Thanks @BRemmelzwaal; I agree. I have modified my answer to use os.path.join instead.